# Need to determine stability of a measure over subsets

Tags: measurement-error, measurement, subset

I have a measure that takes a set of data and spits out a value. I want to determine the stability of this measure in terms of the size of the dataset. I.e, I want to understand how the returns (for getting more data) have diminishing value.

So far I have approached this as follows.

Calculate the value of the measure on

```
1. All of the data
2. 10 sampled subsets consisting of 90% of the data
:
:
n 10 sampled subsets consisting of 1% of the data
```

then I can plot the mean of the trials (with the variance as error-bars) vs the proportion of the data to get a visual guide to how stable the measure is over subsets. I would like to place the intuition gained from such an approach on a more solid foundation. Reading topics / useful statistics much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In many situations what you seek can be deduced mathematically from the formula of the "measure."  This provides many advantages over an empirical study like the one you propose, because it provides insight going beyond just this dataset and can explain *why* it behaves as it does. Could you disclose what your measure is?

Comment: My problem is that the measure is the outcome of a rather complex R script. I will try and realise it as formula when next in the office!