# Assessing stability of a method to less data (subsets of it)

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, measurement, subset

I'm working on a (computational biology) method which provides a result given a set of data regarding a cell. For example, it takes a picture of an object (or a part of it) and assesses the object's weight.

Now I want to assess and prove the robustness of this method for having a smaller set of points. In the example given, that would mean picking random parts of the picture, and seeing the stability of the weights calculated (employing the method on a subset).

So I guess I could take a 1000 such cells (or pictures) which I have, and then subsample each one, and do a correlation between the resulting scores. This works out well, but in the end subsampling is random - so I could do this subsampling a number of times, say a hundred, and then get a hundred correlation scores (and p-values). My question is how to consolidate this into a more solid statistical framework (and assess it's significance).

I got to this (unanswered) [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133232/need-to-determine-stability-of-a-measure-over-subsets), which seems to be going after the same thing, only I don't think it's possible for me to derive a formula for the method like it is suggested there.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question (how can you assess the weight of an object based on part of it?), but you sound like you might be interested in [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29). Yes, resampling is (somewhat) random, but unless you have a *really* hard problem, you can do enough (>=10,000) samples to get stable results, and randomization procedures have been a standard and accepted part of statistics for at least 15 years now. (You can always do five independent bootstraps and see whether the results vary.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa What if it'd be recognizing the object from a picture, and the pictures are of varying resolutions? Say I'm inferring some numerical value about the object based on the picture, and then I want to assess it's robustness to decreasing resolutions by downsampling the resolution of each picture.

Comment: @StephanKolassa re boostratpping - is bootstrapping ok for downsampling as well? So let's assume I did 10,000 such tests as you recommended, what do I present? the mean R-coefficient across the 10,000 tests? And what would be that result's statistical significance? Thanks for the help

Comment: I'd then present the variation of your parameter estimates, e.g., by giving 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles. What the significance is will depend on what your null hypothesis is.